# ExecuteSqlCommand fails in Entity Framework when the command text has a DDL and DML instruction

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6, npgsql

In C#, using NpgSQL to connect on a Postgres database, I'm trying to execute an unique command that have a DDL and DML instructions, however that command not work.

Sample:

```
var m_comandoSQL = @"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.test_55;
CREATE TABLE public.test_55 ( ds_nome VARCHAR(50) );
SELECT * FROM public.test_55;";

var m_modelo = new Modelo(); // Modelo is a dbContext
m_modelo.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(m_comandoSQL);
```

When the ExecuteSqlCommand is called, the following exception is raised

> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): 42P01: relation "public.test_55" does not exist
>
> em Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.DoReadSingleMessage(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean returnNullForAsyncMessage, Boolean isPrependedMessage)
>
> em Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadSingleMessage(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean returnNullForAsyncMessage)
>
> em Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.Execute(CommandBehavior behavior)
>
> em Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryInternal()
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass59.b__57()
>
> em rei_cadastros.InitializeTeste.Main(String[] args)

If I execute the commands separately, no errors happen.

Comment: There's a good chance you're using an old version of Npgsql, can you please check which version you're on and try upgrading to 3.2.x?

Comment: I'm using the Npgl 3.0.5 version and will try update to 3.2.x

Comment: Upgrading the Npgsql to 3.2x version the problem has been solved! Thanks!

Comment: Upgrading the Npgsql to 3.2x version the problem has been solved! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var m_comandoSQL = @"SET client_min_messages = error;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.test_55;
CREATE TABLE public.test_55 ( ds_nome VARCHAR(50) );
SELECT * FROM public.test_55;";

var m_modelo = new Modelo(); // Modelo is a dbContext
m_modelo.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(m_comandoSQL);
```

The reason of error probably is a postgres notice generated by drop table statement when table does not exists.

> IF EXISTS
>
> ```
> Do not throw an error if the table does not exist. A notice is issued in this case.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As Shay Rojansky mentioned, upgrading the NpgSQL to version 3.2.x solved the problem